# A player takes half a standard action, what am I supposed to do?

Tags: dnd-4e, actions, rituals, magic-items

I've got a problem with how to define half a standard action.
The hold portal ritual takes 1 standard action to cast. This is so the player can use it in combat. Now this player wants to create a scroll of this ritual.
The rules of scrolls state the following [page 299 phb1 4e]:

> Time: Casting a ritual from a scroll takes half the time indicated in
>   a ritual’s description, since the creation of the scroll has primed
>   the magic.

So, how should I interpret half a standard action??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no such thing as "half an action", so that means you need to round it.

There are no rules anywhere that suggest that you can do something in less than an action if you use up only part of it (for example; it's not a minor action to move only half your speed, nor it is a move action to only make one of the attacks a power grants) so in this case I'd simply round it up: performing half of a Standard Action takes one Standard Action just like moving half your speed takes one Move Action.

Comment: I see. I'll probably suggest that he can use 2 scrolls (each taking "half a standard action") in a single turn or something.

Comment: I'd be careful with that, or you might get players asking to use half of a Shift power's movement speed and half of a regular Move in a single move action or other such weird trickery. Actions are generally non-divisable.

Comment: I think that he would have half a standard action left OR say actions are a quantum and you can't cut them in half or the multiverse will implode. Depends on how likely your players are to break the game with the rulling

Comment: As far as I can find scrolls are the only time that the casting times are cut in half, taking a move action (or any other action) will still result in the same amount of time spend regardless of the distance. Nonetheless, I think it's best to decide this on a case to case basis.

Answer (score 2):

The second of the Two Principles (on page 29 of the Rules Compendium) says:

> Unless instructed otherwise, always round down even if the fraction is ½ or larger.

I can't find anything to instruct otherwise, so RAW is to treat it as taking no time at all.

---

That said, dividing actions is not something commonly done by the rules, and Hold Portal is rather an edge case in its casting time. I'd be prepared to house rule that it rounded back up to 1 standard action in this case (and warn players in advance that I might do that if it seemed too powerful).

Comment: The problem with "no time at all" is that the Standard Action is also used to initiate the action. Otherwise the scroll would go off immediately when created. You can't use a "No Action" or "Free Action" to activate it, since these are not the same as "0 Standard Actions".

Comment: so in this case he could use an infinite amount of hold portal scrolls (given that he has infinite scrolls). I could live with that since it takes 16 hours and 50 gp to create one scroll but I'll probably limit it to 2 per standard action. The main reason he wanted to create scrolls of the ritual was to have the party help to stop a PC whose life goal is opening every door he encounters.

Comment: @Arno It sounds like you have some conflict between two players at the table. You might also want to ask us about _that_ if it is a significant problem, but it's hard to tell if you're exaggerating and whether it's disruptive to your group or just OK and fun. If it's making things un-fun somehow, that'd be something we could advise in resolving given sufficient information about the situation.

Comment: nah, it's quite fun atm. He just feels his character would do this. Besides if it became a problem I would likely add double doors (empty corridors behind doors) or teleportation traps on opening or if it becomes a real problem I will talk to the player. For now everyone's happy but thanks for the advise.

Comment: @ArnovanderWeijden Good to hear, seems like you've got it managed (I'm glad to see that talking to him is on that list for if it ever becomes unfun :D)

Answer (score 0):

Having it take a full standard action is completely reasonable. If you hadn't asked, I would've just assumed that.

That being said, this is an odd case since one doesn't normally divide actions.

If the player isn't satisfied with needing to use a full action, it would make sense to rule that, with scrolls *only*, half a Standard action is a Minor action (or a Move, if you like).

This way, the player gets to take advantage of the "faster casting" idea from the scroll, but you don't have to deal with any weird half-actions.